# Retrieve email information of facebook account

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oltu

When I get the facebook code, I set the scope in this way:

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
    .authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.FACEBOOK)
    .setClientId(FacebookConfig.APP_ID)
    .setRedirectURI(FacebookConfig.APP_REDIRECT_URI)
    .setScope("email")
    .buildQueryMessage();
```

Now, in the app info on facebook account, I can see that the info provided to the app contains the email address.

[image]

But when I retrieve the infos:

```
OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());  
OAuthClientRequest bearerClientRequest =new OAuthBearerClientRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/me")
                                            .setAccessToken(accessToken)
                                            .buildQueryMessage();

OAuthResourceResponse resourceResponse=oAuthClient.resource(bearerClientRequest, OAuth.HttpMethod.GET, OAuthResourceResponse.class);
```

there is any information about the email address:

```
{"name":"AAAAA BBBBB","id":"12345678901234567"}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Graph API v2.4, you need to specify each field which you want to retrieve explicitly.

E.g.

```
OAuthClientRequest bearerClientRequest =new OAuthBearerClientRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email")
                                            .setAccessToken(accessToken)
                                            .buildQueryMessage();
```